# php - How to get content from an li link with a specific background color?

Tags: php

The external website I'm trying to get content from looks like this:

```
<div class="the_div_class">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="" style="background-color: rgb(252,187,69);">inferno</a></li>
  <li><a href="" style="background-color: rgb(251,212,142);">heat</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far though I only want to get li row content with the style: "background-color: rgb(252,187,69);". Can I add this somehow to the $query?

```
<?php 

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.the_website.com');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = "//div[@class='the_div_class']";
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
var_dump($entries->item(0)->textContent);

?>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get content from an li link with a specific background color?

```
<?php 
...
$query = "//a[@style='background-color: rgb(252,187,69);']";
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

// get text
var_dump($entries->item(0)->textContent);

// get link
var_dump($entries->item(0)->getAttribute('href'));
?>
```

Comment: This is what I would have thought too. Though the query still doesn't seem to find it. Also there are other styles of the a link like "text bold"...etc; would this effect the query? How strict is it?

Comment: It matches it exactly, you never said about additional style properties. You might be better off just just finding all links and then using `getAttribute('style')` in a loop and then strstr() to check for the specific style.

Comment: ahh ok... so it matches exactly. Thanks, working now.